# How to get a select in HTML Agility Pack

Tags: html-agility-pack

I'm trying to get the select element for a particular webpage, but I have trouble doing this.

Here's my code so far.
I'm trying to get the select element in a web page, containing the name "postalDistrictList", and none of my code works.

I also tried htmlweb.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//select") but this returns null.

Does anyone have any idea how I can do this?

```
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            HtmlNode.ElementsFlags.Remove("option");
            HtmlWeb htmlweb = new HtmlWeb();
            HtmlDocument html = htmlweb.Load("https://www.ura.gov.sg/realEstateWeb/realEstate/pageflow/transaction/submitSearch.do");


//            HtmlNode bodyNode = html.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//select");
            HtmlNode bodyNode = html.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("/html/body");
            HtmlNode selectNode = html.GetElementbyId("postalDistrictList");
            HtmlNodeCollection selectNodes = html.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//select[@name='postalDistrictList']");
//          HtmlNode selectNode = html.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//select[@name='postalDistrictList']");
             HtmlNode node = selectNode;
//            foreach (HtmlNode node in selectNodes)
            {
                Console.Out.Write(node.Attributes["options"].Value);
                Console.Out.WriteLine();
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the XPath //./select[@name='postalDistrictList'], i.e.

```
HtmlNodeCollection selectNodes = html.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//./select[@name='postalDistrictList']");
```

should help you get the a collection of the select elements you are looking for.

Comment: The URL supplied in your code does not seem to contain any "select" elements.  Have you tried to run self-contained test where you load a known flat html page which contains a select element as specified?

Comment: The "select" is nested very deep. If you use find, you'll be able to find it.

The exact XPath according to Firebug is:
/html/body/table[2]/tbody/tr/td[2]/div[2]/form/table/tbody/tr[10]/td[2]/table/tbody/tr[2]/td/table/tbody/tr/td/div/select

Comment: Does the "select" come from the page generated on the server-side or generated on the client-side?  Try to turn-off JavaScript and see if you can still locate the "select" element.

Comment: Yup, Javascript turned off, and select is still there.